# TeamCity, no clean-up for certain configuration. No pinned builds, no dependent builds

Tags: teamcity

I'm running TeamCity 5.  I have one particular configuration that is preserving 3500+ past builds, with artifacts, from the last year or so.  It's taking up almost 7 gigs of space so I need to clean up old builds.

The configuration is set to clean up everything older than 30 days or 5 builds.  None of the builds are pinned.  No configurations on the server depend on the artifacts, and even if they did I have un-set "Prevent dependency artifacts clean-up".  Other build configurations clean up, but this particular one doesn't.

Anybody have ideas on what to check next?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out.  I wasn't understanding how TeamCity is preserving old builds.  It's preserving all builds since the fifth oldest successful build, and the fifth successful build was a year ago.  I reduced the cleanup rule to "Clean artifacts more than 30 days older than the last build and older than the **1st** successful build", and got rid of some of the history.  Now, to get the devs to fix their unit tests so this is successful more often... ;)

Also, you can leave the "-th successful build" field blank and limit just on days.

Comment: I can't wrap my my around what this means. However, when I reduced the parameter you specified, it freed gigs and gigs of space. Wish they had made these parameters more intuitive, but thanks for the suggestion.